# HTML5 generating video from images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

i'm wondering, since HTML  and  with javascript are mesmerizing together, if there is a solution in HTML5 to generate a video-file from many images?

For example, you're able to load a video into a canvas and make it appear as greyscaled video, by manipulating the canvas. However, I would like to know, 
if there is somewhat a method to generate a video-file out of that greyscaled version. Would make sense, if you want to send the video via whatsapp etc.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save canvas animation as gif or webm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681683/how-to-save-canvas-animation-as-gif-or-webm)

Comment: @fain182 not quite the same, you could do image to canvas to webm, but this poster is fairly clearly asking about image to webm (or similar video formats).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are currently no built-in API to do video encoding in HTML5. There are [work in progress](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/#mediacapture) though, to allow basic video and audio recording - but it's not available at this time (audio recording is available in FireFox - it is also limited to *streams*).

If you are OK with gif animation you can encode the frames as a gif using one of the encoders out there (see below).

For video - there has been attempts, more or less successful, (the project I had in mind does not seem to be available anymore) but there has been issues from one browser to another.

There is the option of building an encoder yourself low-level style, following video encoding and file format specifications. It's doable but it's not a small project.

In any case, encoding video is a pretty performance hungry task even for native compiled applications. Running such a task in the browser will be a even more slow process and probably not practical for many users (and mobile devices will suck on those batteries).

The better approach IMO (at the moment at least, until the aforementioned API becomes available), is to send images to server and have a server in the back handling encoding jobs, then send the result to client. This way you can use multi-threading, offload the client, use native compiled encoders such as ffmpeg, and the resulting video can be streamed back.

**Some resources**

- [MediaStream Recording API](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html)
- [Gif encoder 1](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/)
- [Gif encoder 2 (NodeJS)](https://github.com/twolfson/gif-encoder)
- [HTML5 Video recording information and status](http://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording)
- [Realtime video encoder (NodeJS/ffmpeg)](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/76000554454/node-js-real-time-video-encoding)
- [libvpx (requires emscripten/asm.js)](https://bitbucket.org/desmaj/libvpx.js/src)

Answer (score 10):

Here we go:

- Article: http://techslides.com/convert-images-to-video-with-javascript
- Demo: http://techslides.com/demos/image-video/create.html *(select multiple images at once)*
- Code: `[just view the source]`
- You can download `.webm` video file

@K3N answer mentions building an encoder. Luckily there is one - https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy - snippet from the article:

> You need a video encoder and today I just happened to stumble on Whammy, a real time JavaScript WebM Encoder.

Comment: As WEBP images format is supported only in Chrome and Opera, Whammy won't work in other browsers(( http://caniuse.com/#search=webp

Comment: @AndriiVerbytskyi Fair point. Client-side encoding is pretty much experimental - here be dragons!

Comment: Appears to be widely supported today, and social media sites like Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, YouTube and Vimeo support WebM as an upload format for video.

Comment: generates video that wont play online or locally, just crashes back to 0

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have built it  using the code provided by tech-slides.
Also I made  a template application where you can take list of images and turn them into video format. You have to edit the code according to your own needs. It is only supported in chrome and YouTube though. So basically in whammy.js you turn the images into canvas in a JavaScript file then turn the canvas into video using whammy.js function. You need to set event listener and load the videos into video tag. Whammy.js only produce webp file. To turn it into mp4:
Load it in YouTube then download it using YouTube as mp4. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just a follow on from @michal's answer, whammy is no longer maintained, however there's a modern fork of whammy encoder at [ts-whammy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-whammy).

See this answer to [get a data URL for an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-url-in-javascript)

```js
import tsWhammy from "ts-whammy/src/libs";

// images can from: canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions)
const images = [
  "data:image/webp;base64,UklGRkZg....",
  "data:image/webp;base64,UklGRkZg....",
];

// Make a 5 second video
const blob = tsWhammy.fromImageArrayWithOptions(images, { duration: 5 });

console.log(blob.type, blob.size);
```