# How to play arraybuffer on video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, arraybuffer

I'm getting images from html canvas and would like to convert these images into a video. Search long and hard. Just want to take a couple of images and make them into a video. I manage to pass multiple images to a library engine and it return me a arraybuffer.

My question:

How can I take a arraybuffer and play it in a video tag or convert it so it can play.

On Request:

```
//You can simply call:
var frames = [];//array to hold each image/frame url
frames.push(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));//get the data url from canvas
```

But my question concern more of using arraybuffer as a uri for a video tag.

Comment: Could you please provide some code of how you are getting the images from canvas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 generating video from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717016/html5-generating-video-from-images)

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using the following solution:

```
const arrayBuffer = null; // your ArrayBuffer goes here
// For example you can fetch it from some URL like 
// const arrayBuffer = await fetch(url).then(r => r.arrayBuffer());
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
const video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// You can now insert video into DOM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use it, You can use mediaStream and then create URL object. Which can be passed to video tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to add a code sample to your answers wherever possible :)