# Creating Video or GIF or time lapse from an array of image URLs

Tags: javascript, image, video

I have got a list of image url form an api endpoint, and i wish to generate a video with these images in javascript.

after the video is created i'd display it on the page, im using react btw.

```
images = [

    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0173.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0126.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0160.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0184.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0177.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0166.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0174.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0167.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0187.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0197.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0190.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0192.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0189.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0188.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0182.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0198.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0196.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0163.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0117.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0199.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0191.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0148.jpg",
    "https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/0132.jpg"
    
]
```

Comment: There's quite a few ways of converting a list of images to a gif on github. If you just want to show it 'like a video' using JS just step through them showing one after the other, perhaps fading between them - depends on what the images are.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717016/html5-generating-video-from-images) can help you

Comment: @AHaworth i tried using that but there is a lot of flashing, because there is a loading time in between switching pictures

Comment: Are you waiting for the window onload event before starting.

Comment: no @AHaworth, what exactly is that?

Comment: If your page depends on images (or anything else that is bulky) to be loaded then it is usual to get it to wait for that stuff to be loaded. Lookup for example the window onload event.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is the [Transloadit /video/merge robot](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/#video-merge). For example, this template here will take all of the files uploaded and then convert them into an animated gif in order to be exported to an Amazon S3 bucket.

```
    {
      "steps": {
        ":original": {
          "robot": "/upload/handle"
        },
        "animated": {
          "robot": "/video/merge",
          "use": {
            "steps": [
              {
                "name": ":original",
                "as": "image"
              }
            ]
          },
          "result": true,
          "duration": 7.8,
          "framerate": "10",
          "ffmpeg_stack": "v4.3.1",
          "ffmpeg": {
            "f": "gif",
            "pix_fmt": "rgb24"
          },
          "resize_strategy": "pad"
        },
        "exported": {
          "use": [
            ":original",
            "animated"
          ],
          "robot": "/s3/store",
          "credentials": "YOUR_AWS_CREDENTIALS",
          "url_prefix": "https://demos.transloadit.com/"
        }
      }
    }
```

While, transloadit doesn't have native react integration, it can be used through uppy's robodog service. Here's a small React snippet that will take an array of files, run it through a specified template, and then output an array of results, using the template from before.

```
    import Uppy from '@uppy/core'
    import { Dashboard } from '@uppy/react'
    import { Transloadit } from '@uppy/transloadit'
    import '@uppy/core/dist/style.css'
    import '@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.css'
    const url_list = ["www.link1.com/image.png", "www.link2.com/image.png", "www.link3.com/image.png"]
    const uppy = new Uppy()
        .use(Transloadit, {
            params: {
          "auth": {
            "key": "YOUR_TRANSLOADIT_AUTH_KEY"
          }
          "steps": {
            "imported": {
              "robot": "/http/import",
              "url": url_list
            },
            "animated": {
              "robot": "/video/merge",
              "use": {
                "steps": [
                  {
                    "name": "imported",
                    "as": "image"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "result": true,
              "duration": 7.8,
              "framerate": "10",
              "ffmpeg_stack": "v4.3.1",
              "ffmpeg": {
                "f": "gif",
                "pix_fmt": "rgb24"
              },
              "resize_strategy": "pad"
            },
            "exported": {
              "use": [
                "imported",
                "animated"
              ],
              "robot": "/s3/store",
              "credentials": "YOUR_AWS_CREDENTIALS",
              "url_prefix": "https://demos.transloadit.com/"
            }
          }
        }
      });
    uppy.on("complete", (result) => {
        console.log("Upload complete! We've uploaded these files: ", result.successful)
    })
    export default function Home() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <Dashboard
            uppy={uppy}
          />    
        </div>
      )
    }
```